# SQL query returning cartesian product

Tags: sql, cartesian-product

I have some tables:

```
Employee: id, name, id_suc, id dep, id_sec
Suc     : id_suc, name
Dep     : id_dep, id_suc, name
Sec     : id_sec, id_dep, id_suc, name
```

Don't blame on me, this is an existing application, I didn't create the Database and can't touch the structure since there is too much data inside and reports depending on it. I'm just trying to modify a report as asked.

I do a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  s.name as sucurs, 
  d.name as depart, 
  c.name as section, 
  e.name AS emp 
FROM 
  employee e 
  join suc s on (e.id_suc = s.id_suc) 
  join dep d on (e.id_dep = d.id_dep) 
  join sec c on (e.id_sec = c.id_sec) 
ORDER BY 
  sucurs, depart, section, emp
```

and brings me a cartesian product. I want:

```
sucurs1, depart1, section1, emp1
sucurs1, depart1, section1, emp2
.....
```

(then on the report I group by suc, then dep, then sec)

instead, I got:

```
sucurs1, depart1, section1, emp1
sucurs2, depart1, section1, emp1
```

and so on. It brings ALL `sucurs`, ALL `depart`, ALL `section` and sometimes duplicated `emp`.

I'm missing something, but don't know what. Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you're always joining the tables to only `employee` - it would seem that `Dep` is **also** linked to `Suc` - so you need a second JOIN condition (join not only on `id_dep` but also on `id_suc`!). Table `Sec` even needs **three** JOIN conditions since it shares three id's with the `Employee` table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  s.name as sucurs, 
  d.name as depart, 
  c.name as section, 
  e.name AS emp 
FROM 
  employee e 
INNER JOIN 
  suc s ON e.id_suc = s.id_suc
INNER JOIN 
  dep d ON e.id_dep = d.id_dep AND e.id_suc = d.id_suc
INNER JOIN 
  sec c ON e.id_sec = c.id_sec AND e.id_suc = c.id_suc AND e.id_dep = c.id_dep
ORDER BY 
  sucurs, depart, section, emp
```

Comment: That made it! Thank you very much! Hope I never have to deal with such kind of structures again :)