# Avoiding Cartesian Product with Inner Joins

Tags: sql, syntax, cartesian-product

I know this has been asked before, but I'm having difficulty in grasping it.  I rarely use raw SQL.
I have three tables - `Session`, `GroupName` and `GroupSessionFeedback`.

I'm joining `Session` to `GroupFeedback` on `idUser`
and I'm joining `GroupName` to `Session` on `idGroup` column.

Here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT s.idSession, 
       g.name, 
       s.Assistant, 
       s.idGroup, 
       s.start, 
       s.end, 
       f.value
  FROM rempad.Session s
 INNER JOIN rempad.GroupSessionFeedback f
    ON s.idUser = f.idUser
 INNER JOIN rempad.GroupName g
    ON s.idGroup = g.idGroup
 WHERE s.start BETWEEN '2013-04-28' AND '2013-05-28'
   AND s.idUser = 22
    OR s.idUser = 23
    OR s.idUser = 24
    OR s.idUser = 26
    OR s.idUser = 27
    OR s.idUser = 28
    OR s.idUser = 42;
```

I want it to bring back unique `idSessions` but it is matching it multiple times because of the Joins and I really haven't an idea what other approach to take.  I could make separate calls to the database - but I'm really trying to avoid hammering the database as it's pretty slow response as it is.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Two points: you are mixing `ands` and `ors`. `And` has precedence over `or`, resulting in `start` filter being honored for iduser 22 only. Other users are simply appended to result. See [Mysql or/and precedence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence). Use `in` or enclose all the `ors` in parentheses. Second point: if performance does not improve then you probably need to revisit indexes.

Answer (score 4):

I used the example on this page : [SQL query returning cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872544/sql-query-returning-cartesian-product?rq=1) to figure it out.  In fairness I did not supply the database structure in my question.  But the problem was that in each of the tables that I was joining there were more than one column that matched so I needed to reflect that in my Join statments.  Here is a sample

```
 INNER JOIN rempad.GroupSessionFeedback f
 ON s.idUser = f.idUser 
 AND s.idSession = f.idSession 
 AND s.idGroup = f.idGroup
```

I hope this helps someone else.
L

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
select {.......}
from session s inner join groupsessionfeedback f inner join groupname g
on s.iduser = f.iduser and s.idgroup = g.idgroup
where {.......}
```

I hope this solves it. However if any other filters are needed in this query, tell me.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, but I believe that your solution is still producing the same results.  It's just two innerjoins written with another syntax, but fundamentally it will still produce a Cartesian product of the tables.  This is what I am hoping to avoid.  But thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this version of the query suffer the same problem:

```
SELECT s.idSession, g.name, s.Assistant, s.idGroup, s.start, s.end, f.value
  FROM rempad.Session s
 INNER JOIN rempad.GroupSessionFeedback f
    ON s.idUser = f.idUser
 INNER JOIN rempad.GroupName g
    ON s.idGroup = g.idGroup
 WHERE s.start BETWEEN '2013-04-28' AND '2013-05-28'
   AND s.idUser in (22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 42);
```

If it is still producing duplicate results, then what do you want the rows to be?  After all, this will fix the problem with multiple `idsession`, but it doesn't return `g.name` or `f.value`:

```
SELECT distinct s.idSession, s.Assistant, s.idGroup, s.start, s.end
  FROM rempad.Session s
 INNER JOIN rempad.GroupSessionFeedback f
    ON s.idUser = f.idUser
 INNER JOIN rempad.GroupName g
    ON s.idGroup = g.idGroup
 WHERE s.start BETWEEN '2013-04-28' AND '2013-05-28'
   AND s.idUser in (22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 42);
```