# Not the correct number of records (joins and cartesian) - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join, cartesian-product

I am running SSMS and trying to write a query to return a big sheet that captures all data from various table for "full market" analysis. However, I either get too little or WAY too much data.

My largest table has 1,025,650 rows. I got this number by doing

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table_name
```

on all my tables. That was the largest number.

What I want: as mentioned above, my desired result would likely be a result with 1,025,650 rows with multiple columns that come from various tables.

What I have tried: (sorry for big blocks)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier, dbo.PUBACC_EN.call_sign, 
    dbo.PUBACC_EN.email, dbo.PUBACC_EN.phone,   
    dbo.PUBACC_EN.first_name,dbo.PUBACC_EN.last_name, 
    dbo.PUBACC_EN.entity_name, dbo.PUBACC_EN.state, 
    dbo.PUBACC_HD.radio_service_code,
    dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date, dbo.PUBACC_HD.last_action_date, 
    dbo.PUBACC_HD.expired_date,
    dbo.PUBACC_HD.effective_date, dbo.PUBACC_BF.buildout_date, 
    dbo.PUBACC_FR.transmitter_make, 
    dbo.PUBACC_FR.transmitter_model, dbo.PUBACC_FR.frequency_assigned,
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_degrees, dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_minutes, 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_seconds, 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_direction, dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_degrees, 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_minutes, 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_seconds, dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_direction 
FROM 
    dbo.PUBACC_EN
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_HD ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_HD.unique_system_identifier 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_FR ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_FR.unique_system_identifier
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_LO.unique_system_identifier
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_BF ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_BF.unique_system_identifier
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_PA ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_PA.unique_system_identifier
```

The above code returns 9,931,904 rows.

So I then tried a smaller query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dbo.PUBACC_HD.radio_service_code, dbo.PUBACC_FR.transmitter_make, 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_degrees, dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_minutes, dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_seconds, 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.lat_direction, dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_degrees, dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_minutes, 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_seconds, dbo.PUBACC_LO.long_direction 
FROM 
    dbo.PUBACC_EN
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_HD ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_HD.unique_system_identifier 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_FR ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_FR.unique_system_identifier
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PUBACC_LO ON dbo.PUBACC_EN.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_LO.unique_system_identifier
```

This returned only 421,432 rows.

My problem and TL;DR :**

I think I am getting a [Cartesian Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872544/sql-query-returning-cartesian-product?rq=1) or my joins are not correct. What would be the solution to my problem?

Comment: well, at least it doesn't looks like the `unique_system_identifier` is very unique

Comment: Is there one, and only one, value for each join you're making? If DBO.PUBACC_HD has 2 matching records, you will bring them both back

Comment: @Lamak, Yeah - this is plauging me - even using two "unique" fields seem to not be unique

Comment: I mean, that's very easy to verify, you should do a `COUNT(DISTINCT unique_system_identifier)` in each of those tables and compare it to `COUNT(*)` to see if they are unique or not

Comment: Wow... this is bad... 248,509 unique "unique system identifiers"... So would it be fair to say that my problem is soley based on the lack of uniquesness in this field?

Comment: That's exactly it. My answer has a query that will allow you to see the full records for the multiples, so you can assess if it's actually a composite key and you need additional fields in your join criteria.

Comment: @MattR it's not only *fair to say*, it is the only cause of your issue

Comment: @HartCO... Just contacted someone within my office... apparently it's common practice for us to have this, because there are multiple records that use the same identifiers and callsigns for our products.
As an analyst this makes my head spin. - Should i delete this post as this is not going to be solved due to "my" error?

Comment: You can't delete it now that there are answers to it, but this is a common troubleshooting process that will likely be seen by others, so it's not unhelpful just because it isn't easily resolved for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that you have multiple values for some `unique_system_identifier` values in some of your tables. If this is a surprise you'll have to dig into the individual tables to find out where the multiples are coming from. You can run a query like this on each table to view the multiples:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT * 
                     ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY unique_system_identifier) AS CT
              FROM DBO.PUBACC_HD
             )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE CT > 1
ORDER BY CT DESC, unique_system_identifier
```

The resolution is to either remove unexpected multiples or to alter your join criteria to ensure a 1:1 join.

Comment: I ran that query and there are 306,000 records showing up for the PA, 622,00 in the BF  table and 905,000 in the BF table. What does this mean?

Comment: It means `unique_system_identifier` isn't very unique. Look at the output of this query to see if there's another field that might make it unique, you can test by adding other fields to the `PARTITION BY` section of the `COUNT(*) OVER()`. When the query returns no records, you've identified a unique key.  For example, maybe there's a date field that is part of the key, you'd alter the above to: `PARTITION BY unique_system_identifier,date_field` to test.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple rows in one of your tables (and definitely in one of the PUBACC_BF PUBACC_PA tables) that have the same value in the "unique_system_identifier" field.

You also want to stop using "distinct" as that hides the true Cartesian and thus hides faults in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be done with `inner join`s, if your maximum row count should be around the row count of the largest involved table. At least your description sounds to me like this. There might also be a need to constrain your result with a `distinct` clause.